# Methods to visualize intersections of 3 dimensional objects?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In multivariate calculus, a common problem will be to visualize either intersections of 3 dimensional objects or the volume enclosed by the intersection of 2 dimensional surfaces.

What are some tips and tricks to do so?

In particular, the question deals with the surface defined by $|x-y| \leq 1, |y-z| \leq 1, $ and $|x+z| \leq 1$. I don't know how to go about visualizing what region this intersection represents.

Comment: Whenever one of the variables is missing, sketch the equation in the plane  of the two named variables. The two dimensional sketch will form a 3D prism that runs along the unmentioned axis.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the process is mentioned in the comment by @John Douma. Suppose you are given an equation $f(x,y)=0$. Since the $z$-coordinate is not mentioned in this equation, this $z$-coordinate does not affect whether or not a given point $(x,y,z)$ satisfies the equation. So, given any line parallel to the $z$-axis, either all of its points satisfy $f(x,y)=0$, or none of its points do. So, to get the set of points that satisfy the equation, you can take the points in the $xy$-plane that satisfy it, and "sweep" or "extrude" them in the $z$-direction. In short, you think about the set/equation in the $xy$-plane, and then extrude in the $z$-direction.

So, for example, the region $x^2 + 4y^2 = 1$ is an elliptical cylinder running parallel to the $z$-axis.

Now take your example of the set of points where $|x-y| \le 1$. The points in the $xy$-plane satisfying this inequality are those with
$$
-1 \le x-y \le 1
$$
These are the points lying in s strip between the two lines $x-y = -1$ and $x-y = 1$. Extruding this strip in the $z$-direction gives you a "slab" of space.

The same process works with an equation that omits $y$. You figure out a region in the $xz$-plane and then extrude it in the $y$-direction.

In your example, you get three slabs, one in each axis direction. Intersecting them gives you a solid region with 6 planar faces.

Draw pictures, or use a 3D CAD system if you're not good at drawing.

Comment: Thanks! Upon posting the questions I got up to your post until "... Intersecting them gives you a solid region with 6 planar faces." I don't know how to take everything before and get to that point, which I suppose takes practice and spatial reasoning

Comment: To be honest, I have trouble visualizing this particular example, too, so don't feel bad. Cases with only two intersection extrusions are much easier.

Comment: If you can find one, look at a drafting book. They typically have pictures of objects as they appear when looking along the three axes.